# Width and Height fix of different images(image grid) even with window size changing in Bootrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to make a grid image panel consisting of different sizes of images in Bootstrap. ( Different size, different ratio images!)

What I'd like to do is to make perfectly straight image grid panel that properly responds to the different window sizes. ( Mobile, or just shrinking Chrome browser situation wise ).

The approach I took was using "col-md-" series to set the width of images beautifully. As I don't know how to set height of each image appropriately ( to be more specific, fix the ratio between height and width of images), I set it as 100px. Definitely, this is not a perfect solution since when shrunk ( Chrome browser for instance ), a height is fixed but a width varies. My goal is to change a height of images accordingly.

```
<% Course.where(:program => 0).each do |course|%>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 item image-container" style="padding:0 0 0 0;  background-color: black; border:2px solid white;" >
    <img class="img-responsive course-image-wow" src="<%= course.thumbnail.url(:original)%>" alt="" data-courseid="<%=course.id%>" style="box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); display:block; width:auto; height:100px;" 
    >
    <div style="text-align:center;" class="homeImageLink vt_font">
      <span style="color:white; font-weight:800;"><%=course.title%></span>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

(The above snippet is Ruby code! )

[image]

The attached image is a current output. If possible, I want images fill from the center not from the left end. ( I think this is a second question, but just in case!! )

Looking forward to seeing anyone's Opinion!!

This is the fiddle that I just created!
https://jsfiddle.net/og4zz9h1/

Best

Comment: please add a jsfiddle to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to align the img block

for example:
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src=""></li>
  <li><img src=""></li>
  <li><img src=""></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ebp1vbf/1/

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can we do the similar way with Div tag with col-md-3 since I can't fix the width of the image and I want to make the website responsive to user's activity

Comment: Of course we can. col-md-3 only sets the width of 25%. See https://jsfiddle.net/1ebp1vbf/2/